# How to calculate the gradient from a jacobian

Tags: least-squares, jacobian, gradient-descent

I am trying to do some least-squares fitting (trying to implement for learning). I can calculate the Jacobian. For 100 points, I have a jacobian of 100 rows of 4 columns (I have 4 parameters to fit). How do I calculate the gradient?

Answer (score 0):

If your Jacobian has $100$ rows and $4$ columns you are looking at the partial derivatives of $100$ different functions relative to $4$ variables. Then your Jacobian looks like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}& ... &\frac{f_1}{\partial x_{4}}\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_{100}}{\partial x_{1}}& ... & \frac{\partial f_{100}}{\partial x_4}\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then the gradient of the $i$th function $f_i$ is the $i$th row of this matrix,
or
$$
\langle \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_2}, \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_4}, \frac{f_i}{\partial x_4} \rangle.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I have a single function  y = f(x1,x2,x3,x4). At a particular \theta how does one calculate the gradient

Comment: @SEU What is $\theta$? I don't think I understood your question the first time. Are you trying to calculate the gradient in a new system of coordinates from the gradient in the old system of coordinates and a change of coordinates map? I think I need a bit more context.